# Необработанное исключение типа "System.OverflowException" в mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

```
void BuildDiagram()
{
    chartRating.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow r in ClientsTable.Rows)
        if (Convert.ToInt16(r[3]) != 0)
            chartRating.Series[0].Points.AddXY(r[1], r[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Convert.ToInt16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5atb9stc(v=vs.110).aspx) выбрасывает [`OverflowException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx) если переданное значение не укладывается в диапазон [`Int16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16(v=vs.110).aspx), т.е. от -32768 до 32767.

Варианты решения проблемы:

- использовать более емкий тип, например `Int32`, `Int64`, или `Decimal`;

```
if(Convert.ToDecimal(r[3])!=0)
```

- проверить какой реально тип у `r[3]` и привести к нему.

Если после этого зачем-то потребуется привести к `Int16`, то нужно учесть границы диапазона, либо привести между числовыми типами с переполнением:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(r[3]);
short shortValue = (short) value;
```

Answer (score -1):

"Исключение, которое выдается, если выполнение арифметической операции, операции приведения к типу или преобразования в проверяемом контексте приводит к переполнению." [На Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.overflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

`Convert.ToInt16(r[3])` - ошибка скорее всего тут.

Если `r[3]` является объектом, который имеет тип `Int32`, то можете использовать следующий метод явного преобразования: `(Int16)r[3]`.

В настройках проекта на вкладке **Build** жмём кнопку **Advanced** и снимаем галочку **Check for arithmetic overflow**, тогда ошибки переполнения не возникнет.

Важно понимать, что при таком переполнении в этом примере `(Int16)r[3]` вы получите неожиданный результат.

Если `r[3]` является строкой, то попробуйте воспользоваться конструкцией: `try {} catch {}`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16` в любом случае проверяет диапазон, независимо от контекста.